# Determine the cardinality of the set $E$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Determine the cardinality of the set:

$$E=\{f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{N} \mid\forall n\in\mathbb{N} \ , f(n)=f(n+1)+f(n+2)\}$$

What can we say about the decreasing functions $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$?

I've tried looking for examples of something similar in some books, but haven't found anything about it.

Comment: Does $\mathbb N$ include $0$ here ?

Comment: @Suzet No, in this case we do not include 0.

Comment: If $\Bbb N$ has no zero, then this set $E$ is empty.

Comment: In that case then, the cardinality is zero since there do not exist any perpetually decreasing sequences of natural numbers.  Whatever the first number in the sequence was, call it $k$, by the $k$'th term in the sequence then having subtracted at least one each time we will have left the realm of natural numbers with nowhere further to go

Comment: In the event it does include zero, you can show that the cardinality is at least that of $\Bbb N$ since the constant sequences for each $n$ live in your set, and it is at most that of $\{f~:~\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z\mid \forall n\in\Bbb Z,~f(n)=f(n+1)+f(n+2)\}$ since it is a superset of yours which you can see is in bijection with $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ since by specifying the values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ you have in effect defined every value of the function in both directions.  Noting $|\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z|=|\Bbb N|$ completes the proof that your set would be of cardinality $|\Bbb N|$

Answer (score 4):

The set $E$ is empty as for any $n \in \Bbb N$, consider $f(n) \in \Bbb N$. Then by construction we must have infinitely many distinct natural numbers $f(n+1),f(n+2),\dots$ such that each of them are $< f(n)$, which is a contradiction as $[1,f(n)) \cap \Bbb N $ is a finite set!